# Why marginTop changed after set?

Tags: javascript, css

I set `marginTop='-1794557px'` for test div by javascript.
But get -1794560px when I use the same method to read `marginTop`.
This problem only occur on firefox. Is it normal?

```js
var x="-1794557px";
document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop=x;
console.log('document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop=' + document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop);
document.getElementById("rst").innerHTML=document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop;
```

```html
<div id="test" style="margin-top: 0px; background-color: #cccccc;">123</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">test margin-top: <span id="rst"></span></div>
```

Comment: I get -1.79456e+06px on chrome ,which is -1794560px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using element.offsetTop instead, it seems to give a more accurate result, check out the snippet, OR use element.getComputedStyle(p)

```js
var x=-1794557;
document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop=x + "px";
var comp = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("test")).marginTop
console.log('document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop=' + document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop, "actual margin:",document.getElementById("test").offsetTop, " computed style: ", comp.toString());
document.getElementById("rst").innerHTML=document.getElementById("test").style.marginTop + ", but the actual marginTop is really its offsetTop: " + document.getElementById("test").offsetTop + " even though that's a bit off, so try the computed style: " + comp;
```

```html
<div id="test" style="margin-top: 0px; background-color: #cccccc;">123</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">test margin-top: <span id="rst"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! My web work correctly when I use offset.
I found it would get value which has a little error when marginTop > 1000000.